# Row Constructor Expression selects not using index

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

we have this table

```
CREATE TABLE `resource_grant` (
  `resource_grant_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `member_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `member_ref` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `resource_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `resource_ref` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `role_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `modified_by` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `modified_timestamp` timestamp(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),
  `deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `parent_grant_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`resource_grant_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `member_ref` (`member_ref`,`member_type_id`,`resource_type_id`,`resource_ref`),
  KEY `member_type_id` (`member_type_id`),
  KEY `resource_type_id` (`resource_type_id`),
  KEY `role_id` (`role_id`),
  KEY `resource_ref` (`resource_ref`,`resource_type_id`),
  KEY `idx_rg_parent_grant_id` (`parent_grant_id`),
  KEY `resource_ref_2` (`resource_ref`,`member_ref`,`resource_type_id`,`member_type_id`,`role_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `resource_grant_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`member_type_id`) REFERENCES `member_type` (`member_type_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `resource_grant_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`resource_type_id`) REFERENCES `resource_type` (`resource_type_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `resource_grant_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `role` (`role_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

and these related tables

```
CREATE TABLE `member_type` (
  `member_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `member_type` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `modified_by` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `modified_timestamp` timestamp(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),
  `deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`member_type_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `member_type` (`member_type`),
  KEY `member_type_2` (`member_type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `resource_type` (
  `resource_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `resource_type` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `modified_by` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `modified_timestamp` timestamp(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),
  `deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`resource_type_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `resource_type` (`resource_type`),
  KEY `resource_type_2` (`resource_type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `role` (
  `role_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `role_ref` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `modified_by` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `modified_timestamp` timestamp(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),
  `deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`role_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `role_ref` (`role_ref`),
  KEY `role_ref_2` (`role_ref`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

and we need to run selects like these ("Row Constructor Expression" syntax) (basically "bulk selects")

```
SELECT rg.resource_grant_id
FROM resource_grant rg
JOIN resource_type rt ON rg.resource_type_id = rt.resource_type_id
JOIN member_type mt ON rg.member_type_id = mt.member_type_id
JOIN role r ON r.role_id = rg.role_id
WHERE
(rg.resource_ref, rg.member_ref, rt.resource_type, mt.member_type, r.role_ref)
IN
(
('759','624962','property','epc-user','role.171'),
('11974','624962','property','epc-user','role.171')
);
```

the selects take ~60s to run, which is unacceptably long

note that there IS an index for (`resource_ref`,`member_ref`,`resource_type_id`,`member_type_id`,`role_id`)

we also don't want to run n individual select statements - we need these "bulk selects".

mysql 5.6 docs talk about this style of select not using indexes but you can make it using some tricks

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/row-constructor-optimization.html

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/range-optimization.html

not sure what's missing for us in order to make it use the indexes

EDIT here's the plan

```
mysql> explain SELECT rg.resource_grant_id  FROM resource_grant rg  JOIN resource_type rt ON rg.resource_type_id = rt.resource_type_id  JOIN member_type mt ON rg.member_type_id = mt.member_type_id  JOIN role r ON r.role_id = rg.role_id  WHERE  (rg.resource_ref, rg.member_ref, rt.resource_type, mt.member_type, r.role_ref)  IN  (  ('759','624962','property','epc-user','role.171'),  ('11974','624962','property','epc-user','role.171')  );
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------------------------+----------------+---------+--------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                           | key            | key_len | ref                      | rows    | Extra                                              |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------------------------+----------------+---------+--------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | rt    | index  | PRIMARY                                 | resource_type  | 38      | NULL                     |       3 | Using index                                        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mt    | index  | PRIMARY                                 | member_type    | 38      | NULL                     |       6 | Using index; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | rg    | ref    | member_type_id,resource_type_id,role_id | member_type_id | 4       | samsDB.mt.member_type_id | 2370237 | Using where                                        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | r     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                 | PRIMARY        | 4       | samsDB.rg.role_id        |       1 | Using where                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------------------------+----------------+---------+--------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.53 sec)
```

Comment: Your row constructor takes the columns from different tables. Of course index is not used.

Comment: Right, but the columns referenced are indexed in those tables. Is there no way to make this work because it cover multiple tables?

Comment: Why do you want to use this row constructor format, which you know wont use indexes under normal circumstances, rather than a more usual WHERE clause format with a combination of AND and OR statements? Are your example values representative of a real-world query you want to run i.e. only the rg.resource_ref value is varying?

Comment: *Is there no way to make this work because it cover multiple tables?* This is possible, but the query must be altered seriously. The filtering by separate tables nust be moved into the subqueries and then joined to main table - on this step the index will be used.

Comment: Can you try to force the index (e.g. use `... FROM resource_grant rg force index (resource_ref_2) JOIN ...`)? You may have some special data distribution, but in general, the current execution plan looks a bit unexpected.

Comment: @NickW I have to use the row constructor format because the select in runtime can be very bulky (trying to select hundreds of rows)

Comment: @Akina I appreciate your replies, but merely pointing out the query won't work and has to change isn't terribly helpful. I KNOW it doesn't work, that's... why I'm posting a question. If you could show show an example of what could make it work as you're referring to that would be more helpful. If not, no need to reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by changing the `where` clause to:

```
WHERE rg.member_ref = '624962' AND
      rt.resource_type = 'property' AND
      mt.member_type = 'epc-user' AND
      r.role_ref = 'role.171' AND
      rg.resource_ref IN ('759', '11974')
```

The existing indexes are not quite optimal for this.  You need an index where the first two keys are `(member_ref, resource_ref)` -- well, except in the most recent versions of MySQL which implement skip-scan index optimizations.

You might be able to change `resource_ref_2` to:

```
KEY `resource_ref_2` (`member_ref`, `resource_ref`, `resource_type_id`, `member_type_id`, `role_id`),
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not surprised at 60s on 5.6.  "Row constructors" have existed for a long time.  But they were not optimized before 5.7.

Either upgrade or rewrite the `WHERE` as Gordon suggests.